# which directories to backup system (no audiovisual data)?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

(I'm fresh Ubuntu user and encounter many problems whose time to find solution or to find info how to revert all changes takes me more than reinstall distribution. I made about 5 Ubuntu reinstall in 7 days.)

(Give me a tip how to restore system. I tried Deja Dup, added all directories inside ./ though that this is entire system partition, but it contains f.e. media directory with non system partitions from another hdd.)

Which directories to chose to backup system (no audiovisual data)? To have all programms back and their configurations (in case of system/programs mess, not in case of disc damage)?

(I have read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HomeUserBackup but it gives me nothing.)

Comment: "To have all programms back and their configurations"  Anyone suggestion to remove /home/ will have you remove any settings you changed.

Answer (score 1):

> To have all programms back and their configurations?

I would suggest: don't. Focus on backing up your personal data. And set your system up such you can re-install where you can simply mount a partition with your personal data. This is also useful when you want to install a new release: I mount my user partition and I am back up and running within 20 minutes. Also works when you want to switch to another desktop.

In case of problems you can simply re-install your system, install the software you use and set that software up.

I have the following setup:

- SSD: /
- HDD: /discworld/

My HDD holds the directories the system creates for my user (ie. `/home/$USER/`; I changed `~.config/user-dirs.dirs` to have it point to that partition).

If you want you can create a post-installation script with all kinds of `apt install` and `apt remove` instructions and include `gsettings` options and run that after a re-install but (for me) became far too complicated and it needed maintenance every other Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
As other answers mentionned, it is mostly a bad idea to backup your system files in case of program mess. The best thing to do is to backup your personnal data (which cannot be reinstalled), and keep a list of your installed software (as mentionned in other answers). Doing it the other way arround is messy and overcomplicated.

**Old answer:**

You must backup `/boot`, `/bin` (actually a symlink of `/usr/bin` ) `/usr`, `/var`, `/etc`, `/lib` (symlink of `/usr/lib`), `/root` is faculative, `/opt`, `/srv` (if it exists), and `/etc` if you want to keep your config. That's all. If you want to save your data, also keep `/home` directory.

I think that the easiest thing to do here is just deleting `/home` and then recreate the folder by logging as `root`and then doing those commands :

- `cd /`
- `mkdir home`
- `chmod 755 home`
- `useradd -m [username]`

And that's it !
I hope it helped you (or other people).

Answer (score 0):

I offer you to backup /home directory...
To a fresh system, you can reinstall others like programs, settings but you can keep your /home directory for your own files...
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to only backup configuration files and a list of the programs that you have installed.

## Backup

To save all (MOST) configurations, take a backup of `/etc/`.
If you are interested in log files and caches, take a backup of `/var`. It also includes your websites if you have a webserver setup.

To take a backup, you can use `tar`. Use it like so:

```
sudo tar --same-owner cvpzf backup_destination.tar.gz directory_to_backup
```

The `c` means create an archive, `v` is for printing out the names of the files being backed up, `p` for preserving permissions of files, `z` for compressing using `gzip` and `f` defined the destination file.

Now, for all the settings of programs which you installed (ones that were not preinstalled or are a part of the core OS) have their configurations under `/home/user/`. So take a backup of that too.

Now to get a list of packages that you can later install on your new system:

```
sudo apt-mark showauto > autoinstalled.packages
sudo apt-mark showmanual > manualinstalled.packages
```

Now save the two files to someplace because you will need those later to restore.

## Restoring:

1. Install backed up packages. **IMPORTANT: Do not extract the backed up `/etc/`, `/home/` or other stuff yet.

To install backed up packages:

```
sudo apt-mark auto $(cat autoinstalled.pacakges)
sudo apt-mark manual $(cat manualinstalled.packages)
```

2. Restore your files.
   Extract `/etc/`, `/home/user` and others.

You can do it like so:

```
cd the_folder_where_you_want_to_restore
sudo tar --same-owner xvpzf backup.tar.gz
```

3. Click on the tickmark in the top-left of the answer if it helped.